# How can Redis listen to hostname in docker network?

Tags: docker, redis, hostname

In redis.conf, bind directive accepts IP but not hostname so in docker env, I can't specify docker compose service name like below.

```
bind docker_compose_service_name(=hostname, not IP address)
```

Is listening to hostname possible in redis?
I want my laravel app container to access redis container with phpredis. So if there is better way to connect, please share as well.

Comment: Generally things in Docker should bind or listen to 0.0.0.0, "all interfaces".  Docker has higher-level controls over what's able to reach a container.  A container won't usually have a fixed IP address to bind to.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Since container IP is dynamic, redis server should listen to 0.0.0.0. Problem solved.